# cloudformation sceptre: How to parameterize a list of json objects

Tags: aws-cloudformation, troposphere, sceptre

I am using sceptre and troposphere to generate my architecture.

In AWS Batch Job Definition, I want to parameterize the Environment of the job definition's container properties:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties.html

The environment is a list of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-environment.html.

But in the context of sceptre, it doesn't seem like I can declare something like this:

```
self.JobDefinitionEnvironment = t.add_parameter(Parameter(
    'JobDefinitionEnvironment',
    Type='List<AWS::Batch::JobDefinition::Environment>'
))
```

In sceptre:

1. Do I have to write my own resolver to solve this problem?  Even if I write my own resolver to resolve JobDefintion::Environment, the resolver returns only a string, not a list of objects.
2. Am I not supposed to parameterize the container properties and hardcode the values in the job-definition.py?
3. I am currently working around by "flatten" out the object, so I can supply the values.  Kinda ugly.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Cloudformation doesn't support `List<AWS::Batch::JobDefinition::Environment>` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)

There are a few approaches to your problem

Note i'm more familiar with using yaml & jinja, but the bellow should work with troposphere too, and i will add examples when i get the chance

### Sceptre_user_data

in `config/<stack_name>.yaml` add

```
sceptre_user_data:
  JobDefinitionEnvironment:
    - <list-goes-here-as-yaml/json>
```

in `cfn/<template>.yaml.j2` add

```
  myBatchJob
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Environment:
        {{ sceptre_user_data.JobDefinitionEnvironment }}
```

### Native

To do it natively, you can use `Type: CommaDelimitedList` and select, this is a bit cumbersome

```
Parameters:
  BatchEnvironmentSetting1:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: MySetting,MyValue

Resources:
  myBatchJob:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Environment:
       - Name: !Select [0, BatchEnvironmentSetting]
         Value: !Select [1, BatchEnvironmentSetting]
```

#### With Conditions and loops

If the native approach works for you then you can make the values optional (and using loops makes this less painful

```
Parameters:
  {% for i in range(20) %}
  BatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ''
  {% endfor %}

Conditions:
  {% for i in range(20) %}
  UseBatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}: !Not [!Equals [BatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}, '']] 
  {% endfor %}


Resources:
  myBatchJob:
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Environment:
       {% for i in range(20) %}
       - !If 
         - UseBatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}
         - Name: !Select [0, BatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}]
           Value: !Select [1, BatchEnvironmentSetting{{ i }}]
         - !Ref AWS::NoValue
      {% endfor %}
```

This kind of looping is one of the places where troposphere might make the code cleaner as you could have a AddEnviornmentSetting function that implements all 3 loops

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can do with sceptre, but with stacker (http://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest) you would just make the definition list a variable, and then use that variable in your blueprint (which is written in troposphere).

An example that might make sense is the open source ECS blueprint:

https://github.com/cloudtools/stacker_blueprints/blob/master/stacker_blueprints/ecs.py#L69-L74 (Where the variable is defined)

https://github.com/cloudtools/stacker_blueprints/blob/master/stacker_blueprints/ecs.py#L69-L74 (where we turn the variable dictionary into a list of objects like ECS expects)

https://github.com/cloudtools/stacker_blueprints/blob/master/stacker_blueprints/ecs.py#L296 (where that is used in the container definition)

Sorry I don't know sceptre well though.  Not sure if you're stuck using it, or if stacker is potentially useful to you.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I am not stuck with sceptre.  Thanks for introducing me to stacker!  BTW, what is the roadmap on bringing it up to speed with Python 3.6?  My shop is starting on re-standarding our usage on Python and the more modern, stable version like 3.6 is version of choice.

Comment: python 3.6 support is in, but is "experimental" - the only reason being we want folks to use it a bit to shake out any bugs.  Any bugs that are found will be more of the type of "this won't update" rather than "oh no it destroyed my stack" though at this point, we've tried to make sure our testing is pretty strong on that point (we do not only functional, but integration tests).

So far things seem to be going really well with it :)